# Append does not work in For Loop

Tags: python, django

```
first_sale_all_menu             = []

for one_product_category in Product_Category.objects.all().filter(slug__in=('3-pack-items-c', '3-pack-items-b', '3-pack-items', '3-pack-items-d')):
    link_to_mamapedia_cat   = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.get_absolute_url()
    mamapedia_category_name = one_product_category.name
    if (one_product_category.image_for_top_menu != None):
        header_image = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.main_picture.url  # TODO use thumbnail
    else:
        header_image = ''

    first_sale_all_menu.append({
        'menu_children_url'         : link_to_mamapedia_cat,
        'menu_children_title'       : mamapedia_category_name,
        'menu_product_image_src'    : header_image
    })
```

Somehow that append() method does not work, it is still empty list for first_sale_all_menu.

Just to make sure, even this does not work:

```
first_sale_all_menu             = []
for one_product_category in Product_Category.objects.all().filter(slug__in=('3-pack-items-c', '3-pack-items-b', '3-pack-items', '3-pack-items-d')):
    link_to_mamapedia_cat   = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.get_absolute_url()
    mamapedia_category_name = one_product_category.name
    if (one_product_category.image_for_top_menu != None):
        header_image = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.main_picture.url  # TODO use thumbnail
    else:
        header_image = ''

    first_sale_all_menu.append({
        'menu_children_url': 'link_to_mamapedia_cat',
        'menu_children_title': 'mamapedia_category_name',
        'menu_product_image_src': 'header_image'
    })
```

But this works:

```
first_sale_all_menu             = []
first_sale_all_menu.append({
        'menu_children_url': 'link_to_mamapedia_cat',
        'menu_children_title': 'mamapedia_category_name',
        'menu_product_image_src': 'header_image'
    })
```

I don't know why, but append() does not work inside my for loop. And yes, link_to_mamapedia_cat, mamapedia_category_name, header_image all have String values.

Ok i got the problem, turns out the query never got executed, wrong Model. Haha.

Comment: Are you sure that the for loop has data to iterate on?

Comment: Silly question, Are you sure that there are elements on the Product_Category query?

Comment: yes, i use debug pyCharm, there's string data for link_to_mamapedia_cat, mamapedia_category_name, header_image.

Comment: guys, turns out the for loop has no data to iterate, haha. I found the problem

Comment: basically the query returns nothing, so the for loop never got executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, very simple, your loop hasn't been executed. You can add an output to check.

```
first_sale_all_menu             = []

for one_product_category in Product_Category.objects.all().filter(slug__in=('3-pack-items-c', '3-pack-items-b', '3-pack-items', '3-pack-items-d')):
    print(1)
    link_to_mamapedia_cat   = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.get_absolute_url()
    mamapedia_category_name = one_product_category.name
    if (one_product_category.image_for_top_menu != None):
        header_image = link_to_home_page + one_product_category.main_picture.url  # TODO use thumbnail
    else:
        header_image = ''

    first_sale_all_menu.append({
        'menu_children_url'         : link_to_mamapedia_cat,
        'menu_children_title'       : mamapedia_category_name,
        'menu_product_image_src'    : header_image
    })
```

Comment: when i use debug in pycharm inside the for loop, there's data for one_product_category, that is why link_to_mamapedia_cat, mamapedia_category_name, header_image have string data.

Comment: But the append simply "never happen", but when i use it outside the for loop (the same exact code, but hardcoded string values). i don't know why.

Comment: no wait, i tried it, yes turns out the query never got executed. That is weird, but when i use debug, it shows string, but when i checked it again INSIDE the for loop, it never hits the for in the first place. You;re right